# Hibernate and Ehcache- How to make sure every "select" goes through the entity cache?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ehcache, second-level-cache

I have an entity (JPA annotations with Hibernate query interface) which has a composite business key of two properties (an `external-id` and a `subsidiary-id` [that's a foreign key]) and a primary db key.

I have a JavaSE multi-threaded process which runs "with respect to a subsidiary" and needs to query/update/insert those entities using that composite key (it gets datasets of those `external-ids`).

I can guarantee that once such a process loads no other process will try to insert/update/remove that subsidiary.

What I want is to load all existing entities of that subsidiary on startup and then have every query for a pair of `[externalId,subsidiaryId]` to go through the cache and only if there's a miss to go through the db. In case one of the threads from the process inserts an entity I of course want that to be added to that cache.

What's the best course of action?

I know there's query caching but from what I can gather that will still be a miss the first time of **every** `[externalId,subsidiaryId]` pair.

Thanks and if there's anything which I'm not clear about please ask

**Update**
I had to stop investigating this issue but now that I've come back to it I think that it's seems reasonable that only the query cache and JB Nizet's answer are the only ones applicable.
I'll accept JB Nizet's answer as it is interesting and I might use it (not sure yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a second-level cache for the entity, query for all the subsidiry's entities at startup (this will fill the second-level cache), and initialize an application cache which would just map `[externalId, subsidiaryId]` to `[id]`.

Then, each time you're searching for an entity with a given `[externalId, subsidiaryId]`, first get its ID from the application cache, then

- if the ID is not in the cache, execute the query, update the application cache, and return the found entity
- if the ID is in the cache, get the entity using its ID, which will go to the second-level cache and avoid hitting the DB

Comment: Hi JB Nizet, thanks for your comment. Your suggested course of action entails the cache maintenance, right? Since my multi-threaded app adds these entities as it goes along. The advantages of using the ORM's facade for cache for me was so that I don't need to enter additional handling for these cases. If this is the only option I have I'm thinking maybe I'm better off with the query cache. I'd love to hear if you think there is a different way within the ORM facede to do this.

Comment: I don't think there is a different way. The query cache can only be populated by executing queries, and these queries will first go to the database if the're not cached yet.

Comment: Yeah, I know there isn't a different way with respect to the query cache itself, I was hoping for a different way with respect to the entity cache. Something like defining for it to also look for the [externalId, subsidiaryId] pair when it misses on the id before going to the db.